# Change Super Dev Mode port parameter in intellij's GWT Configuration

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

I have two GWT projects I want to run simultaneously for development. I like running them with Intellij's GWT Configuration, because it takes care of super dev mode for me.

The issue is that intellij's GWT Configuration has some default values for Dev Mode parameters, like the port number, and I can't figure out how to change them.

If I pass the dev mode parameter `-port 9264`, the logs tell me:

```
Runing CodeServer with parameters: [-noprecompile, -port, 9876, -sourceLevel, 1.7, -bindAddress, 127.0.0.1, -launcherDir, /home/coraythan/.IntelliJIdea14/system/gwt/code.63303291/Books.1f092f4b/run/www, -logLevel, INFO, com.mywebsite.books.Books]
```

So that doesn't do anything.

No space like this `-port9264` and I get the error:

```
Unknown argument: -port9264
Google Web Toolkit 2.7.0
DevMode [-[no]startServer] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-whitelist whitelist-string] [-blacklist blacklist-string] [-logdir directory] [-logLevel level] [-gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address] [-codeServerPort port-number | "auto"] [-[no]superDevMode] [-server servletContainerLauncher[:args]] [-startupUrl url] [-war dir] [-deploy dir] [-extra dir] [-modulePathPrefix ] [-workDir dir] [-XmethodNameDisplayMode NONE | ONLY_METHOD_NAME | ABBREVIATED | FULL] [-sourceLevel [auto, 1.6, 1.7]] [-XjsInteropMode [NONE, JS, CLOSURE]] [-[no]incremental] module[s]
```

If I add the square brackets like it looks like it should have `[-port 9264]`, it doesn't replace the pre-existing port parameter, and tries to load a module

```
Runing CodeServer with parameters: [-noprecompile, -port, 9876, -sourceLevel, 1.7, -bindAddress, 127.0.0.1, -launcherDir, /home/coraythan/.IntelliJIdea14/system/gwt/code.63303291/Books.1f092f4b/run/www, -logLevel, INFO, [-port, 9264], com.mywebsite.books.Books]
Super Dev Mode starting up
   workDir: /tmp/gwt-codeserver-7935707369622390541.tmp
   Loading inherited module '[-port'
      [ERROR] Unable to find '[-port.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
Loading modules
   [-port
      Loading inherited module '[-port'
         [ERROR] Unable to find '[-port.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
```

Does anyone know how you can add / replace dev mode parameters in Intellij's GWT Configurations?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The -port parameter change the port of the web server where as the parameter
-codeServerPort change the port of the code server.

Using this configuration:

[image]

starts the web server with port 9264 and the code server with port 8765:

[image]

Comment: Ha! So I was on the right track, I just didn't realize that when the logging showed `-port, 9876` that was actually referring to the `-codeServerPort` (which makes no sense). Anyway, that's awesome, it's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @el-hoss, this lead me to confirm the `Dev Mode parameters` can be specified for those given at http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html:
[image]

According to the rules given at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-gwt.html:
[image]